# Angular JS Dynamic Template pass variable

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-components

I have a component that I want to pass a variable to.

Basically my component is called by:

```
<profileimage></profileimage>
```

I want to pass it an ID by

```
<profileimage userid="user.ID"></profileimage>
```

I would be able to then use that ID in the controller to load an image

```
function ProfileImageController($scope) {
   var ctrl = this;
} 
var app = angular.module('creatif')
    .component('profileimage', {
       templateUrl: 'components/profileimage/profileimage.html',
       controller: ProfileImageController
   });
```

Comment: What's stopping you?

Comment: @31piy I am unsure how to access userid?

Comment: Include your component's definition in the question.

Comment: @31piy have updated the description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `bindings` to receive the variables in your custom component.

```
.component('profileimage', {
   templateUrl: 'components/profileimage/profileimage.html',
   controller: ProfileImageController,
   bindings: {
     userid: '<'
   }
});
```

Then you can use `userid` in your controller by `this.userid`. Go through the [angular's documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component) to know more.

**Bonus Tip**:

Move your directive definition out of the controller function.

```
function ProfileImageController($scope) {
   var ctrl = this;
}

angular.module('creatif')
  .component('profileimage', {
     templateUrl: 'components/profileimage/profileimage.html',
     controller: ProfileImageController,
     bindings: {
       userid: '<'
     }
  });
```

Looks more readable, no?